# How to switch conf tomcat with maven

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I have ,in a java high envirgure project using Maven, to add integrations test. To do that, I must add a new test's database  (minimalist true copy of the database). Until then it's good.
By against the problem is that I have two differents configurations in my file:

> ***\web\target\tomcat\conf\context.xml***

So I always put a ressource in a comment.
exemple of ressource :

```
<Resource
auth = "jdbc / soarepo"
driverClassName = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
logAbandoned = "true"
maxActive = "32"
maxIdle = "32"
maxWait = "10000"
name = "jdbc / soarepo"
password = "..."
username = "..."
removeAbandoned = "true"
removeAbandonedTimeout = "60"
type = "javax.sql.DataSource"
url = "jdbc: oracle: thin: @ ..."    
/>
```

***Q: How do I switch from one to another ressource with Maven?***

> I already use a profile for integration tests. So I have to change what resources when the profile is called ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the [Maven Tomcat Plugin](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.1/tomcat7-maven-plugin/) to run your web application, you can specify the path of a custom server-dependent deployment descriptor, *context.xml*, using the [***contextFile***](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.1/tomcat7-maven-plugin/run-mojo.html#contextFile) property:

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>integration-tests</id>
    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
          <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.1</version>
          <configuration>
            <contextFile>/path/to/context/file</contextFile>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
  </profile>

  .. Other profiles ..

</profiles>
```

Comment: Great to be in help :)